# applying sharepoint foundation masterpage to all sites using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to apply a custom masterpage to all sites within a sharepoint enviroment think along the lines of

1. http://sharepoint/
2. http://sharepoint/site1
3. http://sharepoint/site1/1
4. http://sharepoint/site2/1

I want to be able to using powershell apply a custom masterpage to each of the sites. I know that using

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint 
$web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom_v4.master" 
$web.Update()
```

Can anyone kindly help with the loop for all sites please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe array of url to `Foreach-Object`:

```
'http://sharepoint/',
'http://sharepoint/site1',
'http://sharepoint/site1/1',
'http://sharepoint/site2/1' | Foreach-Object {
  $web = Get-SPWeb $_
  $web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom_v4.master" 
  $web.Update()
}
```

or do it in imperative style:

```
$urls = 'http://sharepoint/', 'http://sharepoint/site1', 'http://sharepoint/site1/1', 'http://sharepoint/site2/1'

foreach($url in $urls) {
  $web = Get-SPWeb $url
  $web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom_v4.master" 
  $web.Update()
}
```

Comment: Thanks stej, is it possible to loop through every site by only providing the toplevel site http://sharepoint? I don't know any of the site names

Comment: Is there any command that returns list of site names? I don't know about SharePoint almost nothing..

Comment: @DiverDan you should be able to query SPSite instances AllWebs collection

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to apply the master to the entire site collection:

```
foreach ($site in get-spsite -url http://sharepoint*) {

     $web = Get-SPWeb $site
     $web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom_v4.master" 
     $web.Update()

}
```

For more information about get-spsite you can read this post at [sharepoint automation](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2009/04/working-with-spwebinfo-objects-using-powershell/). Hope helps!

Comment: thanks empo, what is $site is that the same as a var? do I need to set $site to be anything before the foreach loop

Comment: $site is the current $site in the loop. It's foreach syntax. You could write the same by: `get-spsite -url http://sharepoint* | %{...}` I immagine, where inside the curly brackets you would use $_ in place of $site.

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on the simple url positioning of sites. i think what you want is this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://localhost"
$site.AllWebs | foreach-object { `
               $_.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custompagename.master";    
               $web.Update()
}
```

The AllWebs property returns all sites within the site collection.  If you do use variations, you may want to exclude them from the list some somehow use ?{ $_.Name -like 'en-us'  } and pipe that before the foreach pipe.